# Can broken time-reversal symmetric system never be in equilibrium?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, symmetry, equilibrium

Detailed balance condition is necessary for equilibrium so as to avoid limit cycles and detailed balance condition implies time-reversal symmetry. Now, if for example, in a 1D lattice of an Ising spin system, we fix the direction of a spin or give a magnetic doping, we disrupt the detailed balance condition and hence the time-reversal symmetry. So can the system reach in equilibrium and can we apply monte carlo techniques to study such a system?

Comment: Detailed balance (reversibility) is *sufficient* to guarantee that a (finite-state, irreducible) Markov chain converges to equilibrium, but it is by no means *necessary*: any aperiodic (finite-state, irreducible) Markov chain converges to the (unique) stationary distribution. That being said, freezing a spin does not prevent you from having detailed balance (you just restrict the states of your Markov chains to configurations satisfying this constraint).

Comment: Can you explain why a freezing spin does not prevent a detailed balance condition? Because clearly if we bring in some spin, that site is going to behave differently than the others and is going to have some inducing effect on that spin.

Comment: First, note that that's precisely what you do when you want to simulate your system with, say, + boundary condition. Ok, let me be a bit more specific now and consider one (simple) MC algorithm for your Ising system. Let $\mu$ denote the Gibbs measure of the Ising model that you want to sample from. At each step, you select one spin x at random, uniformly, and set it to $+1$ with probability $\mu(\sigma_x =1 | \sigma_y,y\neq x)$ and to $-1$ otherwise. You can then easily check that this defines a reversible Markov chain, with stationary distribution $\mu$.

Comment: Now, observe that if you want one of your spin, say the spin at $0$, to be frozen (say, $\sigma_0=1$), then nothing changes: you simply never choose $x=0$ (since in that case you would not change the value of the spin in any case). So the chain remains reversible.

Comment: The fact that some spins behave differently from the others is of course irrelevant. You can apply the same algorithm for a system in which each spin is subject to a different magnetic field, so that *all* spins have different behaviors...

Comment: But for you to get this point, the best thing to do is just check that the detailed balance condition is satisfied even with some frozen spin. It is a one-line computation. (If you don't want to do the computation, then just look at the discussion of the Gibbs sampler in Section 3.10.3 of [this book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/index.html).)

Comment: Thanks! I get your point. So basically we ignore the frozen spin and do the computation. But in case of real systems, does the frozen spin disrupt the equilibrium even locally?...sorry I am an undergrad trying to figure things out, pardon me if the questions are naive.

Comment: OK. I will have a look at the book. :)

Comment: Impurities will not prevent the system from reaching equilibrium (fortunately, since there are not that many pure systems in nature ;) ), although, of course, the corresponding probability measure is modified (in particular close to the impurities, but sometimes more drastically). And don't worry, this site's entire purpose is to answer questions :) .